# Language Browser Detection in Odoo/Python

Tags: python, xml, browser, odoo

I'm new to Odoo and Python.
I would like to know how to detect the browser's language in odoo using python.
Is it also possible to implement the condition in an XML file?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may to look at the [langdetect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langdetect)

```
>>> from langdetect import detect
>>> detect("War doesn't show who's right, just who's left.")
'en'
>>> detect("Ein, zwei, drei, vier")
'de'
```

Exemple from : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langdetect/1.0.1

No ideas for the XML part